# Alternative of fsockopen with curl in php

Tags: php, web-services, sockets, curl

I am trying to call a web service of a shipping company in my php code and get the result xml. I have this sample code and i want to know if there is an alternative using curl.

Code:

```
  function doPost($_postContent) {
    $postContent = "xml_in=".$_postContent;

    $host="test.company.com";
    $contentLen = strlen($postContent);

    $httpHeader ="POST /shippergate2.asp HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        ."Host: $host\r\n"
        ."User-Agent: PHP Script\r\n"
        ."Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
        ."Content-Length: $contentLen\r\n"
        ."Connection: close\r\n"
        ."\r\n";

    $httpHeader.=$postContent;


        $fp = fsockopen($host, 81);

        fputs($fp, $httpHeader);

        $result = "";

        while(!feof($fp)) {
                // receive the results of the request
                $result .= fgets($fp, 128);
        }

        // close the socket connection:

        fclose($fp);

        $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result,3);
}
```

Can i call it using curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CURLOPT_PORT` option to change the port to 81. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

```
$url = "http://test.company.com/shippergate2.asp";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 81);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "PHP Script");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postContent);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: thnx for the reply. what do you mean by "standard"?

Comment: Sorry, that may have been confusing. Standard HTTP 1.1 is RFC 2616. The example you posted is standard HTTP, and this would work for that.

Comment: do i still have to include the headers: content type/length etc...?

Comment: cURL will handle the `Content-Type`, `Content-Length`, `Host`, and `Connection` headers. You'll have to set `User-Agent` manually - I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a complete solution is needed but I suggest checking this basic CURL wrapper for PHP https://github.com/shuber/curl